# Smallest $k$ such that $4900$ divides $600k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> (A) Express 600 as the product of its prime factors.
>
> (B) Given $4900=2^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7^2$, find the highest common factor of $600$ and $4900$
>
> (C) Given that $600k$ is a multiple of $4900$, write down the smallest possible value of $k$ such that $4900$ divides $600k$.

I have done both (a) and (b) and have tried (c) but I could not find the answer.

Comment: For correct wording, we probably need to ask for the smallest *positive* integer $k$.

Comment: Wait a minute. Isnt the answer 1/600? Because 1 surely divides 49? And one more thing. Does 49/600k is an integer or the inverse? Please edit and clarify your question.

Comment: K i will show the full question, not sure if it will help though

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\frac{600\cdot k}{4900}=\frac{6\cdot k}{49}$$

So, this needs to be an integer $\implies 49$ divdes $6\cdot k$

As $(49,6)=1, 49$ must divide $k$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are only looking for positive integer solutions.

HINT: Think about the prime factorisation of each side